# How to securely stored in SD Card Videos in Android?

Tags: android, security

I'm writing an application i want to read videos from SD Card.but i want to store videos (Mp4) files securely in SD Card.
-Please give some links are examples.

Thanks,
Chandu

Comment: Securely how? If you're talking about a DRM system, don't bother. Anything you can come up with on your own is going to be trivially easy to defeat. Remember - any DRM you come up with has to be PERMANENTLY effective, in perpetuity. On the other hand someone has to defeat your system only ONCE and the content is available to all forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your content on the SD card, any application installed on the device can access it and anyone that can pop out the SD card and put it into another device can read it as well.

Android devices, by design, give users the capability to do whatever they want with their devices and the CD card is considered common storage, available to all applications. There is nothing you can do to prevent this, short of encrypting the content (and then you still need to put the keys somewhere...). All you can do is make it more difficult to get to your content; if the device can access it, a determined attacker can as well by reverse engineering the hoops you're making the application go through.